# How to set ThreadPool (Dsnd_t_max) in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

WSO2 ESB is not loading all proxies (more than 20). Then we increased following two values in the startup script and it worked:

```
-Dsnd_t_core=120
-Dsnd_t_max=600
```

But then we encountered several fatal issues of the WSO2 ESB. Several JMS proxies were blocked and did not consume anymore messages. The worst thing of all: NO ERROR in the carbon.log!

In addition the CPU load on the server went up to 100%.

A restart did not solve the problem, only deactivating scheduled tasks or proxies solved the problem.

We now discovered, that a VFS proxy is creating exactly 120 threads (JConsole). With each transport.PollInterval it creates a new Thread.

**Which values do you use for the -Dsnd_t_core and max?**

**Why is a VFS proxy creating a new thread (see jconsole) a t each PollInterval?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I know, WSO2 ESB thread is based on java.util.concurrent ThreadPool.

In this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) you can read about some ThreadPool characteristics like when will it create a new thread, the queue mechanism, and reject task policy.

**Which values do you use for the -Dsnd_t_core and max?**
-Dsnd_t_core is the minimum number of threads inside a ThreadPool. So WSO2 ESB will automatically create thread as much as you set the -Dsnd_t_core. The default value is 20. WSO2 ESB will create 20 vfs-worker if you don't specify the -Dsnd_t_core. 
-Dsnd_t_max is the maximum number of threads inside a ThreadPool. WSO2 ESB will stop create a new thread if the maximum number is reached.

**Why is a VFS proxy creating a new thread (see jconsole) a t each PollInterval?**
WSO2 ESB will create a new thread in these conditions :

> - If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> - If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a   request rather than adding a new thread.
> - If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be
>     rejected.

So, as long as your queue is full and the maximum number of threads is not reached, WSO2 will create a new thread to handle a process. The PollInterval is set to specify the delay before your service start to poll the message or file from the source folder. 
You can set the maxQueue number to unbound (-1) so the queue will never full and new thread will never be created.
I also found something from the JConsole. 1 service/1 proxy service will be handled only by 1 thread. I still trying to figure this out and make 1 service/1 proxy service is handled by 2 or more thread (multithread).
Hope this will help answer your question :)

Comment: Nice answer and seems logic. But one thing I don't understand, it creates a new thread at each PollInterval even if the queue is empty - that's strange. And theses threads will then be in the WAIT mode and continue existing, even if they never had a message...