# apache common-vfs ThreadPool Configuration

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, apache-commons-vfs, wso2-esb

Is there any configuration for common-vfs to set the ThreadPool? I use this vfs in WSO2 ESB apache Synapse. I already look for the documentation etc, but i found nothing said about ThreadPool in vfs. So how can i configure it? Thanks, for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added following config to `bin/wso2server.bat` at the long line 158:

```
-Dsnd_t_core=120 -Dsnd_t_max=600
```

This will work up to quite some vfs proxies. But I discovered that there are as much threads created as you configure the core. [See the bug here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15361501/583513)